# React - InputMask maskPlaceholder is saving as input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masking, data-masking

I'm using InputMask with `maskPlaceholder = {"XXX"}` and when I check the `currentState.value` after focusing on the input, the value holds the placeholder value and not null.

I don't want the placeholder to be a part of the value itself, and before I insert any character I want the currentState.value to be null.

Tried to use `maskChar={"X"}` but this gives me a warning:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `maskChar` prop on a DOM element

Answer (score 0):

I've used null instead

```
maskChar={null}
```